# Can you show me how to make this pseudocode using `LaTeX`?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic, pseudocode

[image]

Can you show me how to make this pseudocode using `LaTeX`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us what you've tried to far. E.g., have you searched this site for keywords such as "algorithm" and "algorithmic"? If so, was there anything you found helpful?

Comment: Take a look at the package `algorithm2e`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\newcommand{\algheading}[1]{\State \textit{\bfseries #1}}
\algdef{SE}[FOR]{ForAll}{EndForAll}[1]{\algorithmicforall\ (#1)}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}%
\algdef{SE}[IF]{If}{EndIf}[1]{\algorithmicif\ #1}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}%
\algdef{C}[IF]{IF}{ElsIf}[1]{\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif\ #1}%

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Procedure to construct asymmetric matrix}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \algheading{Inputs:}
    \State \quad Set of nodes~$N$ and arcs~$A$
    \State \quad $c_{ij}$ information (energy consumption of drone by dynamics in arc~$(i,j)$
    \State \quad $c_{ijk}$ information (energy consumption of drone's rotation in consecutive arcs~$(i,j,k)$
    
    \addvspace{.5\baselineskip}
    
    \algheading{Constructing an asymmetric matrix}
    \ForAll{node $i,j \in N$}
      \If{arc $(i,j) \in A$, and has headwind}
        \State Generate a flight network with $c_{ij} + p_d (v_d) \frac{d_{ij}}{v_f}$
      \ElsIf{arc $(i,j) \in A$, and has tailwind}
        \State Generate a flight network with $c_{ij} - p_d (v_d) \frac{d_{ij}}{v_f}$
      \ElsIf{arc $(i,j) \in A$}
        \State Generate a flight network with $c_{ij} = \infty$
      \EndIf
    \EndForAll
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```